# Spring Boot 2.2.x giving 301 through gateway facing internet after migration from 2.1.8

Tags: spring-boot

We have a Spring Boot application currently built with 2.1.8.RELEASE with cloud Greenwich.SR4 and this application can be accessible through both Internet and Intranet. To meet some of the compliance, we need to migrate to Spring Boot 2.2.x. As part of the same, migrated to SB 2.2.5 and Cloud Hoxton.SR3 also tried with Hoxton.RELEASE.

When migrated to SB 2.2.5, application can be accessible through Intranet, but not through internet. Below are the verbose logs captured through curl.

**With Intranet**

```
$ curl -v https://oauth2-authserver-dev.nonprod.abc.com/api/ie/oauthserver/actuator/health
*   Trying 10.223.35.9...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to oauth2-authserver-dev.nonprod.abc.com (10.223.35.9) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=Minnesota; L=Plymouth; O=ABC Group Inc.; CN=oauth2-authserver.stg.svc
*  start date: Jun 17 15:36:08 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Jun 16 15:36:08 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "oauth2-authserver-dev.nonprod.abc.com" matched cert's "oauth2-authserver-dev.nonprod.abc.com"
*  issuer: C=US; ST=Minnesota; L=Minneapolis; O=ABC; CN=ABCInternalIssuingCA2
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /api/ie/oauthserver/actuator/health HTTP/1.1
> Host: oauth2-authserver-dev.nonprod.abc.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200
< Cache-Control: private
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Type: application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Thu, 09 Apr 2020 17:14:50 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host oauth2-authserver-dev.nonprod.abc.com left intact
{"status":"UP"}
```

**With Internet (from External)**

```
~ $ curl -v https://apigw-dev.abc.com/api/ie/oauthserver/actuator/health
*   Trying 168.183.43.71...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to apigw-dev.abc.com (168.183.43.71) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; postalCode=55343; ST=Minnesota; L=Minnetonka; street=9900 Bren Road East; O=ABC Group Inc.; OU=ABC Tech ETP & Info Srvcs; CN=apigw-dev.abc.com
*  start date: Feb 24 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Feb 23 23:59:59 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "apigw-dev.abc.com" matched cert's "apigw-dev.abc.com"
*  issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /api/ie/oauthserver/actuator/health HTTP/1.1
> Host: apigw-dev.abc.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302
< Content-Length: 0
< Cache-Control: private
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< Location: https://apigw-dev.abc.com/api/ie/oauthserver/actuator/health
< Date: Thu, 09 Apr 2020 17:09:37 GMT
< X-Kong-Upstream-Latency: 29
< X-Kong-Proxy-Latency: 6
< Via: kong/1.1.2
< Set-Cookie: 086c31780e9921a51376a20749328373=2385c3080d735964e8e509811a8ad7d8; path=/; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: BIGipServerapps.nonprod.abc.com_80=327929610.20480.0000; path=/
<
* Connection #0 to host apigw-dev.abc.com left intact
```

Is there anything we can find from the above logs? Please let me know, if any other information required to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what updated in Spring Boot 2.2.5 onwards. Initially we thought, these is some incompatibility with SB 2.2.5 and tried to upgrade to SB 2.3.0, still faced the same issue. So explored various options to set in `bootstrap.yml` file. The following combination worked perfectly.

```
server:
  port: 8443
  http:
    port: 8080
  http2:
    enabled: true
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-alias: <cert_alias_name>
    key-store-type: JKS
    key-store: file:certificate.jks
    key-store-password: <key_store_password>
    trust-store: ${server.ssl.key-store}
    trust-store-password: ${server.ssl.key-store-password}
    trust-store-type: JKS
  forward-headers-strategy: framework
```

Here, we have added `server.http2.enabled` and `server.forward-headers-strategy` properties additionally. Then we started getting `2XX` response.